# Comments on solution to a rather complicated EGARCH model

Tags: volatility

I do a lot of nonlinear parameter estimation, but do not have any experience in finance. I posted the following answer to a question about a EGARCH model on 
cross validated.  I have copied the model description and
solution to here so that I have a self-contained question.

I have the data if anyone is interested. My junk email address is xbobolson@gmail.com.

$$\Delta y_{t} = \alpha + \sum^{12}_{j}\beta_{j}S_{j,t}(1 + \gamma_{1}D_{1,t} + \gamma_{2}D_{2,t}) + \varepsilon_{t}$$

$$\ln(\sigma^2_{t}) = \omega_{0} + \sum^{2}_{i=1} \omega_{i} |\frac{\varepsilon_{t-i}}{\sigma_{t-i}}| + \lambda \frac{\varepsilon_{t-1}}{\sigma_{t-1}} + \omega_{3} \ln(\sigma^{2}_{t-1}) + \sum^{12}_{j}\delta_{j}|S_{j,t}|(1 + \rho_{1}D_{1,t} + \rho_{2}D_{2,t})$$

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250274/additional-nonlinear-terms-in-the-egarch-model-maximum-likelihood-estimation.

It took me  a while to develop a stable estimation scheme using AD Model Builder. I am curious to know from the GARCH experts if this is simple to do with some existing software.

```
 # Number of parameters = 35  Objective function value = -89.3242  Maximum gradient component = 7.45641e-05
 # alpha:
 -0.0184773755820
 # beta:
  0.0776272250120 -0.0282086700728 0.0105870775566 -0.796727950111 -0.0329451864914 0.0574720791322 -0.00769006016788 0.0634996913172 -0.271844797702 -0.00148927676168 -0.107749917570 -0.0235315136652
 # gamma:
  -1.28418932915 0.253708104907
 # omega0:
 -0.0288892906469
 # omega:
  -0.0390792976332 0.0693366331859
 # lambda:
 -0.0174406066104
 # ls1:    log standard deviations for periods 1 and 2
 0.521640582874
 # omega3:
 0.995013839900
 # delta:
  -0.0454107838910 0.0442755011514 0.0848044432830 -0.202324778947 -0.0184050276271 0.00891208520744 0.00954099100492 0.00610579281349 -0.0181269442505 0.0502826182040 -0.0135121954742 -0.143376988696
 # rho:
  0.144999774670 1.88445900772
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a follow-up question to a cross validated question/answer and thus seems to be a better fit there.

Comment: @LocalVolatility well it is a follow up question to my answer,  which I spent a lot of time on, to try and help this guy, since no one else seemed interested. So I think that makes it a new question.

Comment: IMO GARCH fits equally well on stats and here. If it doesn't  get much attention on stats let's give it a chance over here. It would be good to have the question stand on it's own though.